# WPF Dispatcher.PushFrame vs WinForms Application.DoEvents?

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, doevents

In WinForms, Application.DoEvents method has been regarded as evil by some people. Can anybody tell if its counterpart of Dispatcher.PushFrame in WPF is safe to use?